# How to generate 15 inputs with loop for and run just once?

Tags: javascript

how to generate 15 inputs with loop for,
 every input with their own "id" and run just once?

```
<input type="button" onclick="generate()">
<script>
function generate(){
for(var i=0; i < 15; i++) {
}
}
```

Comment: Huh??? Please try again... can't understand you

Comment: what input you want to generate input box?? input data?? clarify it a little more.. Your For loop is wrong though -- do it like this --  for(var i=0 ; i<15;i++){...}

Comment: I'm sorry, but in more than one way, this question just shows zero effort.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I guess "zero effort" is looping in the for loop :)

Comment: @swapnesh: But as you pointed out, without even bothering to do *that* right (or mark it up right).

Comment: @swapnesh input type="text" and the loop is ok, in javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is that what are you looking for?

```
for(var i=0 ; i<15;i++)
{
     var input = document.createElement('input');
     input .setAttribute('id',"input"+i);
     document.getElementById("formName").appendChild(input);
}
```

Comment: Change for(var i=0 ; i<15;i++{ TO for(var i=0 ; i<15;i++){

Comment: but it doesn't run just once.

Comment: Form elements belong within a form, not as a direct child of the document body.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a form with an ID of `myForm`:

```
window.onload = function(){

    var form = document.getElementById("myForm");

    for(var i=0; i<15; i++)
    {
        var input = document.createElement('input');
        input.type = 'text';
        input.name = 'myInput_' + i;
        input.id = 'myInput_' + i;
        form.appendChild(input);
    }

};
```

This will give you 15 text inputs each with a unique name and ID in the format `myInput_i` where `i` is the number from 0-14.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id='elements'></div>
<script>
for(var i=0;i<15;i++){
document.getElementById('elements').innerHTML=document.getElementById('elements').innerHTML+"<input type='text' id='type"+i+"'>";
}
</script>
```

Give the id and the input type what you want.

Comment: It's better to manipulate the DOM rather than appending raw HTML, you don't have to worry about escaping and also you won't lose any existing event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

The function take the ID of the div where you want to put the fields, and the second parameter the number of fields that you want.

You could do like that, but if your project will use most javascript DOM manipulation, you should maybe use jQuery.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>

    </head>

    <body>
        <form>
            <div id="divForPlacement">

            </div>
        </form>

        <script>
            function putInputFields(div, number) {
                var oDivForPlacement = document.getElementById(div);
                if(oDivForPlacement === undefined || oDivForPlacement === null) return;
                var currentField = null;

                for(i = 0; i < number; i++) {
                    currentField = document.createElement("input");
                    currentField.setAttribute("id", div + "-field" + i);
                    currentField.setAttribute("type", "text");
                    oDivForPlacement.appendChild(currentField);
                }

            }
            putInputFields("divForPlacement", 15);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```