# How can I generate three buttons in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I know how to generate only one the button. I'm doing it this way:

```
var mylist = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth']
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * mylist.length)
var word = mylist[rand]

var btn = document.createElement('input')
btn.id = 'b1'
btn.value = word
btn.type = 'button'
document.body.appendChild(btn)
```

But I need to generate a few buttons(for example 3 buttons).
        document.body.appendChild(btn)

Comment: Use a for loop, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13722547/1161948

Comment: Learn the language basics, like arrays and loops; this is trivial. After you've mastered the simple stuff, then you'll have a problem when you attach onClick listeners to them that will cause the last button to activate no matter which one you press--that's a real problem, and we'll show you how to fix that when you get there.

Comment: You should use `btn.setAttribute('id', 'b1')` and `btn.innerHTML = word`

Comment: @Matías Both aren't ideal suggestions. Why use `setAttribute` when `id` is available for free? It's also not wise to insert potentially random HMTL into a button when a value is all that's required.

Comment: `const input = document.createElement('input')` then `input.value = 'foo'` will create an empty input tag because you can't set the value of a button with `value`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just wrap your logic in a for-loop .

**Example :**

```
var mylist = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth']
var rand = null; 
var word = null;
var threshold = 3


    for(var i = 0 ; i < threshold ; i++){

        rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (mylist.length - 1)) + 1;
        word = mylist[rand];
        var btn = document.createElement('input');
        btn.id = 'b' + i;
        btn.value = word;
        btn.type = 'button';
        document.body.appendChild(btn);

    }
```

Updated with proof :

http://codepen.io/theConstructor/pen/WoJEGy?editors=1010

Hope this helps.

Comment: This code won't work as is, because of `word` being undefined.

Comment: Updated to reflect

Comment: in your code example you have , var mylist = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth'] ...that should be mylist

Comment: I think you're getting me confused with OP. It helps to provide working code examples when the situation is as straight forward as this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129955/discussion-between-kptheconstructor-and-josephgarrone).

Answer (score 1):

Most performant solution as you're only appending the buttons to the DOM just once by using a document fragment.

```js
const mylist = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth']
const frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

for (let i = 0, listLen = mylist.length; i < listLen; i++) {
  let button = document.createElement('input');
  button.type = 'button'
  button.id = `b${i + 1}`;
  button.value = mylist[Math.floor(Math.random() * listLen)]

  frag.appendChild(button);
}

document.body.appendChild(frag);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a for-loop in conjunction with the `<button>` element (rather than `<input type="button">`).

```js
var list = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth']

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    var btn = document.createElement('button')
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length)
    btn.textContent = list[random]
    document.body.appendChild(btn)
}
```